# How to draw border around QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a QListWidget with QListWidgetItem assigned a thumb image.

[image]

I would appreciate if you show how to make a color border around of the QListWidgetItem

Here is the Photoshoped image showing a concept:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, os

class MyClassItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtGui.QListWidgetItem, self).__init__(parent)       


class ThumbListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(ThumbListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.listItems={}

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)

        self.listWidgetA = ThumbListWidget(self)

        for i in range(7):
            listItemAInstance=MyClassItem()
            name='A'+'%04d'%i
            listItemAInstance.setText(name)
            listItemAInstance.setBackgroundColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGray)   
            if i%2: listItemAInstance.setBackgroundColor(QtCore.Qt.gray)

            icon=self.getIcon(name)
            listItemAInstance.setIcon( icon ) 

            self.listWidgetA.addItem(listItemAInstance) 

            listItemBInstance=MyClassItem()
            name='B'+'%04d'%i
            listItemBInstance.setText(name)
            icon=self.getIcon(name)
            listItemBInstance.setIcon( icon )

        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.listWidgetA)      

    def getIcon(self, name):
        thumbpath=os.path.expanduser("~")+'/thumbs/' +name+'/'+name+'.jpg'
        if not thumbpath: return
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(thumbpath)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(thumbpath))

        img = QtGui.QImage(64, 64, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
        img.fill(QtGui.QColor(96,96,96))     

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(img)
        font = painter.font()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setPointSize(18)     

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor('black'))
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(img.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, name)
        painter.end()
        img.save(thumbpath, 'JPG')

        icon = QtGui.QIcon( thumbpath )
        pixmap = icon.pixmap(64, 64)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
        return icon

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(720,480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every class that derives from `QWidget` supports CSS styling. What you could do is something such as:

```
lwi = QListWidget()
lwi.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item { border: 0px solid red }")
```

For more info, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop

You can also style your entire application, but apply a certain part of styling only to `QListWidgetItem` by putting it as a prefix.

C++ example I found:

`app.setStyleSheet("QListWidget { background: red; } QListWidget::item { background: yellow; } QListWidget::item:selected { background: blue; }");`

Comment: I am getting: `AttributeError: 'QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'` Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, style the entire application similar to the syntax of "C++ example I found". Code is nearly identical.

Comment: In order to get a border around QListWidget I would have to to style every widget with CSS? Isn't it too much of the effort solution?

Comment: No. As I noted, you can set the stylesheet to the entire application, but then in the stylesheet string itself place `QListWidget::item { border: 0px solid black; }`. This will cause only the QListWidgetItem(s) to have the CSS applied to them. I have updated the first part of my answer to give you one possible solution.

Comment: To customize a single `QListWidgetItem` after an entire application was modified with `app.setStyleSheet("QListWidget...");` we should be using `lwi.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item { border: 0px solid red }")` ?

Comment: Ops, still getting the same `AttributeError 'QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'`

Comment: This time I updated my code to reflect the change - Try calling the `setStylesheet()` to `QListWidget()`. This will however apply the CSS to all `QListWidgetItem()` elements within that `QListWidget()`

If you want to select only a specific `QListWidgetItem`, you have to use its `QObject` name (which is the simple name in Qt Designer e.g.). The way you'd use that for example is `listWidget.setStylesheet("QListWidget::item#qobject_name { background-color: #fff }")` - this will cause the background-color to only be applied to the `QListWidgetItem` with the name of `qobject_name`

Comment: Thanks Deusdies! You rock!